# Diode's volt-ampere characteristics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics

The Problem is that

> If the reverse saturation current is $10\ \text{nA}$ ($1\ \text{nA}=10^{-9}\ \text{A}$), Calculate the forward current while the forward voltage is $0.6\ \text{V}$. And explain why the calculative solution is different with actual result.

I know that I should use the Shockley ideal diode equation $I=I_S(e^{v_D/v_T}-1)$ ($v_T=26\ \text{mV}$ in room temperature) to solve the problem easily. I substitued $I_S=10^{-9}\ \text{A}$, $v_D=600\ \text{mV}$ and $v_T=26\ \text{mV}$ into the equation, I got that forward current is $10.524\ \text{A}$. But I see no difference, I think my result is the same with the fact. So that is, if we perform a real experiment, we would get a result that the forward current is $I=10.524\ \text{A}$.

Because its threshold voltage $V_{th}$ is about $0.5\ \text{V}$, when the forward voltage goes beyond threshold voltage, the current will increase quickly. So I think my result is rational. But my thought is not the correct solution of the problem apparently.

I also googled the problem, but I didn't find satisfying solutions. And my fellows are also confused. So I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Note that 10nA is not 10$^{-9}$A.

Comment: Note that, at large enough currents, the non-zero series resistance of physical diodes becomes significant.

Comment: While this obviously derives from a homework problem I think it is a question about the physics involved and therefore a perfectly valid question. I would not vote to close.